# Populate TastyPie Field With Different Resource Content During Hydrate?

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

How can I best populate a field in a TastyPie resource with the *contents* of another record during the `hydrate` process?

I have the following `hydrate` function defined in a resource to populate the "meta" field in a model:

```
def hydrate_meta(self, bundle):
    '''
    This will popular the `meta` field with a snapshot of the employee record, if the `empid` is set.
    '''

    if bundle.data['visitor']['empid']:
        # split the employee resource so we can get to the actual empid number
        empid_split = bundle.data['visitor']['empid'].split('/')

        # query the employee record, the `-2` index is the actual empidinteger
        meta_values = Employee.objects.filter(empid= empid_split[-2]).values('division', 'program', 'subprogram', 'base_city', 'base_state', 'base_country', 'group_abbr')[0]
        for k, v in meta_values.iteritems():
            meta_values[k] = v.encode('utf8')
        bundle.data['meta'] = meta_values

    return bundle
```

This does exactly what I want it to do, but it sure is messy!

Note that I'm pulling the contents of the field out and saving certain fields in object form to a "meta" field.  This is because an employee record can change over time and I want a snapshot of it when this record is created.

Is there a more direct way I can reference and pull the content of a resource to assign to this "meta" field?